# block ping from host to host using iptables (I am the wireless access point)

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm really new to networking and linux system. So please help me in this:
- I have my phone acted as the wireless access point, and other devices like all my LAPTOPs connected to it to create a LAN network. How can I use iptables to block (for example ping request, reply) from host to host.

P/s: I also try to block forward chain using

```
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

But it doesn't work. Host A can still ping to Host B. The blocking forward chain only helps me to block them (hosts in LAN) access the internet.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```bash
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -j REJECT
```

it will work

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this using iptables on your AP (phone), because the traffic doesn't actually go through iptables on your phone. This is link-layer traffic, which I believe will be handled by the WiFi chip on your phone (at the driver layer, won't even reach the kernel).

You might be able to do it if you can modify driver settings of your phone's WiFi chip - this is highly unlikely though.

I could be wrong though - let us know what you find out.